# How to get total rows with output parameter in mssql SP using php zend framework?

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, zend-framework

Here is my code in zend DAL function
records fetch with inout parameters working fine but trouble with output parameter to get total row counts matching with request statement
Please help me out.

```
    $UserId = ($sname=='Uid' && $sval != '' ? $db->quote($sval) : 'NULL');
    $MessageId = ($sname=='id' && $sval != '' ? $db->quote($sval) : 'NULL');
    -------
    -------

    $stored_proc_stmt = "exec my_sp $UserId, $MessageId, $Sender, $Receiver, $Status, $MessageData, $Operator, $StartDate, $EndDate, $recordstart, $recordend, $recordcount";

    $pdo_stmt = $db->PREPARE($stored_proc_stmt);
    $pdo_stmt->execute();

    $result = $pdo_stmt->fetchAll();

    print_r($result); 
exit;
```

Answer (score -1):

put the keyword OUTPUT after your last variable name & make sure the variable is declared as OUTPUT in your stored proc.

Comment: Thanks for response but its not resolved its giving application error after insert OUTPUT in last of output parameter and i have also tried below but its returned below error.

Comment: [message:protected] => There are no more rows in the active result set.  Since this result set is not scrollable, no more data may be retrieved.

Comment: I have also tried 
$pdo_stmt->bindParam(1, $RecordCount, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);